# ReactNative; How to call new component to open new screen?

Tags: react-native

I want to open new screen from Nextpage.js ,after "onPress" worked, everything still same, NextPage not show on screen but not error. How should I do?

```
import NextPage from './NextPage';

function onClick() {
   <NextPage/>
}
```

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = {onClick}>
        <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: item.code }]}>
          <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemCode}>{item.code}</Text>
        </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't call a screen like that. If you want to navigate to any other screen in your case **NextPage**, you should define it in your navigation stack first. After that, you can call function **navigation.navigate("NextPage")** to navigate to next page.

**Navigator file:**

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as React from 'react';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Next from '../screens/Next';
    
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App({initialRouteName = 'Home'}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Next" component={Next} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Suppose you are navigating from Home to NextPage**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default function Home(props) {
  function onClick() {
    props.navigation.navigate('NextPage');
  }

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={onClick}>
      <View style={[styles.itemContainer, {backgroundColor: item.code}]}>
        <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemCode}>{item.code}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try